# Genexus: Cannot run my Knowledge Base. Set required properties

Tags: java, postgresql, genexus

I have a  Knowledge Base with postgresql and java environment. But when I want to run an application I have this error: Set required properties in Build process

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure de Data Base conexion in preferences - datastore

Answer (score 0):

Does the database exist? I'm not seeing the database name in the dialog. Select a DB in the drop-down list, or create a new one by typing the name and clicking the "Create database" link.

[image]

Comment: Is not possible. I also tried that, does not work either. Because there is not connection to the DB.